# Redirecting OLD url to NEW url

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I am moving to a NEW url.  The previous URL was an established blog so there are quite a few URLs that need to redirect so I COULD use 301 redirect in .htaccess but the issue is that we want the core URL to redirect to a certain page.

I have already attempted:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain.com [NC,OR] RewriteCond % . 
{HTTP_HOST} ^www.olddomain.com [NC] RewriteRule ^(.*)$ 
https://newdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

and

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/$ newdomain.com [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.olddomain.com$ RewriteRule (.*)$ 
http:/www.newdomain.com/blog/$1 [R=301,L]
```

So the redirects should work like this:

```
http://olddomain.com/path/to/page
redirects to http://newdomain.com/path/to/page
EXCEPT http://olddomain.com/
redirects to http://olddomain.com/blog
```

What is the most efficient method of redirecting without having to hand code over 200 redirects? Nothing I have found is working.

Comment: You can use redirect plugin. That will redirect all the old URLs to the new URLs.

Comment: @Raghav he can, if (and only if) there is still WordPress on the old url ;)

Comment: The main problem here, is that there is a conflict between these urls. /blog is also a /path/to/page ;) Are there any other urls that should not get redirected to new site?

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż. Yes you are absolutely right.